# Any heroku/rails approach to prevent accident db data destruction?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, rake

I am at a point where I have multiple production heroku apps and several more in development.

For the apps in active development, i often run commands like heroku run rake db:setup, rake db:seed to reset data while I am still doing early development.

There is a risk that I could accidentally run these commands while in a heroku command prompt for a production app which would be bad.

In short, is it possible to disable certain rake tasks(db:reset, db:setup, db:seed) for heroku apps rails.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a task dependency to the appropriate 'dangerous' tasks:

```
task :env_check_development => :environment do
    raise Exception.new("CAN ONLY RUN IN DEVELOPMENT") unless ::Rails.env.development?
end

task 'db:migrate' => :env_check_development
```

Then:

```
$ RAILS_ENV=test rake db:migrate

rake aborted!
CAN ONLY RUN IN DEVELOPMENT
```

Comment: In a rails 3 generated app. I am guessing this would go somewhere like this? lib/tasks/dependencies.rb ?

Comment: @koa When I tested it, I put it directly in the Rakefile; but I believe you can put it under lib/tasks/*.rake as they're all loaded at runtime.

Comment: Very clever approach. Thanks!